# How to output to the console "SUCCESS" after a successful launch, and "ERROR" after an unsuccessful one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-apps-script, puppeteer

*The question is:*

I'm currently working on **Node.js** with the **Puppeteer library** and I need to print ***"SUCCESS"*** to the console after a successful run and ***"ERROR"*** after a failed run. But I don't quite understand how to do it.

I will be grateful to everyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the whole thing in a try...catch

```
try {
  // Your Code Here
  console.log('Success')
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log('Success'); console.log('error');`
https://nodejs.dev/learn/output-to-the-command-line-using-nodejs

Comment: You misunderstood me, I need the word SUCCESS to be displayed after a successful script run, and ERROR after an unsuccessful one.

Comment: You can use lambda expression to check if the script is running -> return success